# Как запретить выполнять функцию, пока не выполнится предыдущая?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 2 функции, обе запускаются по нажатии на одну кнопку поочерёдно, как я могу запретить выполнять вторую функцию пока не выполнится первая?

Я знаю, что можно добавить одну переменную и переключать её в конце каждой из функции, но хотелось бы узнать можно ли как-нибудь по-другому это реализовать.

Comment: При этом у меня это не кнопка, а блок, то есть способ с disabled на кнопку, пока выполняется функция не подходит

Comment: Поскольку в js функции в принципе не могут выполняться одновременно, нужно больше подробностей. Непонятно что именно у вас выполняется. Но вообще переменная-флаг вполне стандартный способ

Comment: Вот ссылка https://q1zin.ru/globalus/
сделайте ширину мобилы, появился бургер меню, если нажимать на неё спокойной, то всё ок, а если много раз нажимать она начинает ехать

Comment: Поставьте в начале функций `openmenu()` и `closemenu()` проверку на значение `btnMenu` и если оно не такое, как нужно, делайте return.

Answer (score 1):

Можно на время выполнения анимации делать ссылку некликабельной через `setTimeout`:

```js
let link = document.querySelector('a')
link.addEventListener('click',function(){
  this.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
  setTimeout(()=>{this.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'},1000) 
  document.querySelector('.content').classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  height: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

.content.active {
  height: 30px;  
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Click</a>
<div class="content">Контент</div>
```

Возможен еще вариант через событие `transitionend`.
Конкретно в вашем случае это событие надо добавить на элементы с классом
'header__menu--strech'. Насколько я понял проблема возникала именно с ними.

```js
let link = document.querySelector('a')
let content = document.querySelector('.content')

content.addEventListener('transitionend',function(){
  link.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'
})

link.addEventListener('click',function(){
  this.style.pointerEvents = 'none'  
  content.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  height: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

.content.active {
  height: 30px;  
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Click</a>
<div class="content">Контент</div>
```

Comment: Думаю, что в данном случае, лучше делать не через таймер, а через событие [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event).

Comment: @UModeL спасибо, не знал о таком событии. Обновил ответ, если я правильно понял его применение.

Comment: да, всё верно. Теперь не нужно вручную указывать задержку в таймере. А всё знать невозможно - я сам иногда подскакиваю на стуле, когда вижу какую-нибудь полезнейшую фичу доступную ещё с первых версий браузеров, а я о ней и знать не знал :)